# Cant access children in component used as element in Route (react-router-dom 6.3.0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Im using `react: 17.0.2` and `react-router-dom: 6.3.0`.

My current `App.js` snippet looks like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Routes>
                    <Route element={<Layout/>}>
                        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}  />
                        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}  />
                        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>}  />
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path='/' element={<Intro/>}/> 
                </Routes>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The route to `'/'` should not use the `Layout` component, so I need to exclude it from the context.

Within `Layout.js` I need to access the `children` like so:

```js
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(children)
  return (
        <div>
            <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
  );
};
```

But `children` are `undefined` in the above example. I can access `children` in `Layout.js` when I rewrite `App.js` to the below snippet, but then `'/'` is also rendered with the Layout.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Layout>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}  />
                        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}  />
                        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup/>}  />
                        <Route exact path='/' element={<Intro/>}/> 
                    </Routes>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

How can I access `children` in `Layout.js` and render path `'/'` without the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Route` and `Routes` work a little differently in v6. The `Route` and `React.Fragment` components are the only valid children of the `Routes` component, and other `Route` components the only valid children of the `Route`. [Layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) ***must*** render an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) component for the nested routes to render their contents into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```